# Windows boot manager overwrites my boot order uefi bios samsung

Tags: linux, windows, uefi

In the UEFI firmware in my Samsung ativ boot 5 laptop I have 'UEFI OS' (which is Grub2, Linux etc..), 'Windows Boot Manager'(Windows 8.1). I want to change boot order to:

1. UEFI OS
2. Windows Boot Manager

BUT when I pick Windows 8 from my grub and then want to swich to my Linux (Manjaro) OS the boot order is overwrite and the first one is Windows Boot Manager. If I'd use just Manjaro Linux then the boot order isn't overwrited.

What Windows does to my boot order? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted Windows boot manager and then used Windows cmd via livedvd to recreate windows boot manager and it worka Mike a charm, but i dont know why ;)